# how to implement multiprocessing for function that takes 6 parameters with different types and sizes

Tags: python, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

I have a function that takes 5 or more parameters as inputs, these parameters have different types and sizes, how do I apply multiprocessing in this case.

Let's say in this dummy sample

the function:

def func(arr1, arr2, arr3, mtx1, mtx2, st):

```
# the function will output three arrays that has the same size as the arr1
result1 = np.zeros((len(arr1), 1))
result2 = np.zeros((len(arr1), 1))
result3 = np.zeros((len(arr1), 1))

# the function will make iteration through the 0 to the length of the arr1
for i, _ in enumerate(arr1):
    # it does a lot of computations using the #th number of arr1, arr2, arr3, but takes the whole matrices mtx1 amd mtx2 
    # some details of the calculation based on the setting of the string 

return result1, result2, result3
```

the main function is to define all the parameters and then input to the function.

if **name** == '**main**':

```
arr1 = np.array([100,200,300])
arr2 = np.array([400,500,600])
arr3 = np.array([700,800,900])
mtx1 = np.array([[1,2,3,4,5],[6,7,8,9,10],[11,12,13,14,15]])
mtx2 = np.random.rand(10,10)
st = 'string'

results = func(arr1, arr2, arr3, mtx1, mtx2, str)
```

I have tried to use the Pool and map as other people suggests, like:

```
p = Pool()
results = p.map(func, arr1, arr2, arr3, mtx1, mtx2, st)
p.close()
p.join()
```

This would give the error:

map() takes from 3 to 4 positional arguments but 8 were given

Most of the examples of multiprocessing I found online takes the same size of arrays as function inputs, and the function only does quite simple math calculation. But it is not my case, how should I solve this problem?

Thanks!

Comment: I guess you should read a bit of documentation to understand your error with [`map()`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.Pool.map). But there is a fundamental problem here: `multiprocessing.ThreadPool` will be completely useless if you perform one single function call. It will distribute multiple function calls to several threads, it will not optimize one function call to bypass the GIL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your usage of `map` is a bit off. The second argument should be an `iterable` - i.e a tuple or a list. Like so:

```
results = p.map(func, (arr1, arr2, arr3, mtx1, mtx2, st))
```

For multiple calls to the same function you can try using starmap: https://docs.python.org/dev/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.Pool.starmap

The arguments for a starmap are expected to be an iterable that will be unpacked for your function.